# Can Visual Studio nuget package manager exclude pre-release packages?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, nuget, t4scaffolding

I'm using a package for generating email from Razor views caller MvcMailer. This package depends on T4Scaffolding (>= 1.0.7). T4Scaffolding in turn depends on EntityFramework (>= 4.1.10311.0).

This shouldn't be a problem because I have Entity Framework 5.0.0 nuget in my project.

For some reason, Entity Framework 6.0.0-alpha1 (Prerelease) is being imported as the dependency of T4 scaffolding, in addition to my existing EF nuget. This is screwing up EF migrations commands because the package manager console is getting confused about which version of EF it should be using.

I'm not sure where the problem lies. How can I tell T4Scaffolding that it already has the required dependencies in place?

Answer (score 1):

Solved...

Entity Framework 5.0.0 was only installed in one of the projects. When I tried to add the MvcMailer to the Tests project (which didn't have EF reference) nuget went and got the latest version of all dependencies, which in the case of EF was the Alpha.

So solved my problem, but still seems wrong to import a pre-release package as a dependency...